# Automatically build Maven Project in case of a dependency upgrade

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, build-automation

I am using Jenkins for CI/CD. Jenkins is integrated with my GIT account and as soon as there is an update in the code, Jenkins will build it automatically.

Lets suppose I am using Spring Framework and the version of the Spring framework gets updated. How can I use Jenkins and Maven to automatically build all the projects that were using the Spring framework?? Is there any plugin that will do it? Would be great if someone can share some tutorials/urls etc for the same?

Comment: This is not how maven is intended to be used.  You chose a version for a dependency which is immutable.  Changing versions can bring problems, you can't do it automatically.

Comment: It should be done automatically, it makes more sense. For example, I am using a Spring Security dependency in around 100 projects. Lets suppose Spring Security gets an important security upgrade. It does not make sense to build all those projects manually, there should be some way that will build all those projects automatically.

Comment: I understand now, I've added answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own parent pom and use a [dependency management section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Then in your child pom you will use the dependency but not specify a version, i.e. the version will be specified in the parent once for all children. You still need to include the dependency in each module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>example-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```